# Type safe container for Bipredicate

Tags: java, oop, generics, design-patterns, wildcard

I have a design problem that I'm not sure how to solve.
I've created an `Evaluator` class that evaluates a parsed expression. The expression is of shape `amount > 50`. The operator is used to understand which predicate must be created. Then, the LHS is sent to a different object to get its actual value. The value can be `String`, `Integer`, `Double` and more.
My problem starts when I try to create the correcet `predicate` and initialise it with the proper values. I get warnings that it isn't type-safe, using a raw type etc. I'd like to solve this issue if I can and not suppress the warnings. My current thought is creating a container class which I named `Value`, that's generic. But I'm stuck on continuing this line of thought. My code:

```
public class Evaluator {
    static PredicateFactory predFactory = new PredicateFactory();


    public boolean evaluate(String[] expression, Data data){ // currently doesn't actually work, just testing
        BiPredicate predicate = predFactory.createPred(expression[1]);
        predicate.test(data.getAttribute(expression[0]), 50);
    }
}

public class PredicateFactory {


    public BiPredicate<?,?> createPred(String operator) {
        return switch (operator) {
            case "<" -> (BiPredicate<Double, String>) (i, j) -> i <  Double.parseDouble(j);
            case ">" -> (BiPredicate<Double, String>) (i, j) -> i >  Double.parseDouble(j);
            case "from domain" -> (BiPredicate<String, String>) (i, j) -> i.endsWith("@" + j);
            default -> null;
        };
    }

public class Value<T>{
    private T val;

    Value(T val){
        this.val = val;
    }

    public T getVal(){
        return this.val;
    }
}


public class Data {
    private int id;
    private int total_price;
    private String date;
    private String email;
   ....

    Data(int id, int price, String date, String email, ){
        this.id = id;
        this.total_price = price;
        this.date = date;
        this.email = email;
.....
    }

    public Value<?> getAttribute(String attribute){ 
        return switch(attribute){
            case "value" -> new Value<>((double) this.total_price);
            case "email" -> new Value<>(this.email);
            default -> null;
        };

    }
}
```

Thank you for any pointers

Comment: If you are sure that only the right types will be inputted (as arguments when calling the predicate), then suppressing the warning should be completly fine and you don't need to worry about it. Otherwise you could use "Object" as the type for your predicate and then check the type of the object inside the labda (predicate) using "instanceof". That should make the warning go away, but would be unnecessary if there can never be an incorrect input.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @IntoVoid , I am positive that the right types will be inputted. I have complete control over this. But, isn't it a bad coding habit to suppress the warnings? I'd like to avoid long switch:cases of instanceofs, feels overly complicated and unscalable

Comment: That's why I would recommend using an Object as the type of your predicate and then just cast the object inside your labda to whatever you need. If instanceof is not used then when an incorrect argument is inputted it will throw an error (this is good though since you will directly know if your code can produce a state where an incorrect data type is inputted) (if you don't use instanceof than there will probably be another warning, but this time inside the labda and not where you call it). I really can't think of another solution that does not require a wrapper class

Comment: The `oop` tag seems misplaced here. In oop, data and logic are combined. Here data and logic are separated. Perhaps the goal is functional programming instead?

Comment: @IntoVoid I'll try using Object then, but would love to hear your input about the wrapper - I'm not very experienced and trying to make this design the best it can be, so I'm willing to implement what I have to if it's good design. @jaco0646 , you may be right - though I am only separating data and logic in this specific case. Would you say it would make more sense the `Data` class deals with the boolean evaluation logic?

Comment: there you go. (Added it down below)

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
public BiPredicate<Object, Object> createPred(String operator) {
    return switch (operator) {
        case "<" -> (i, j) -> (Double) i < Double.parseDouble((String) j);
        case ">" -> (i, j) -> (Double) i > Double.parseDouble((String) j);
        case "from domain" -> (i, j) -> ((String) i).endsWith("@" + j);
        default -> null;
    };
}
```

or using a wrapper / holder class (but this requires you to create a extra instance for every value, meaning that it won't be as efficient. So I would prefer the implementation mentioned above):

```
public BiPredicate<Holder, Holder> createPred(String operator) {
    return switch (operator) {
        case "<" -> (i, j) -> i.number < Double.parseDouble(j.string);
        case ">" -> (i, j) -> i.number > Double.parseDouble(j.string);
        case "from domain" -> (i, j) -> i.string.endsWith("@" + j.string);
        default -> null;
    };
}

public static class Holder {
    public double number;
    public String string;

    public Holder(double number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Holder(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }
}
```